CMake Can't Find Gazebo Package (Installing Gazebo11 with ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 22.04)
Title says what the issue is. Gazebo won't build because CMake can't find the "gazebo" package. Here is a script I made with the commands needed to install ROS Noetic, Catkin, ArduPilot, and Gazebo11:
#!/bin/bash

# install build dependencies
echo "# Installing build dependencies #"
sudo apt-get install curl git g++ cmake -y

# install conda and mamba
echo "# Installing Conda and Mamba #"
curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
bash Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh -b -p "${HOME}/conda"
source "${HOME}/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
source "${HOME}/conda/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh"
echo 'source $HOME/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'source $HOME/conda/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
conda activate
conda install mamba -c conda-forge

# install ROS noetic
echo "# Installing ROS Noetic #"
mamba create -n ros_env python=3.11
mamba activate ros_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --add channels robostack-staging
conda config --env --remove channels defaults
mamba install ros-noetic-desktop
mamba deactivate
mamba activate ros_env
mamba install compilers cmake pkg-config make ninja colcon-common-extensions catkin_tools rosdep

# install Catkin and setup workspace
echo "# Installing Catkin #"
#sudo apt-get install python3-wstool python3-rosinstall-generator python3-catkin-pkg python3-catkin-pkg-modules
cd ~
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin init
cd ~/catkin_ws
wstool init ~/catkin_ws/src
rosinstall_generator --upstream mavros | tee /tmp/mavros.rosinstall
rosinstall_generator mavlink | tee -a /tmp/mavros.rosinstall
wstool merge -t src /tmp/mavros.rosinstall
wstool update -t src
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro `echo $ROS_DISTRO` -y
catkin build
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sudo ~/catkin_ws/src/mavros/mavros/scripts/install_geographiclib_datasets.sh
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/Intelligent-Quads/iq_sim.git
echo "GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=${GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH}:$HOME/catkin_ws/src/iq_sim/models" >> ~/.bashrc
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin build
source ~/.bashrc

# install ArduPilot
echo "# Installing ArduPilot #"
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot.git
cd ardupilot
Tools/environment_install/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh -y
. ~/.profile
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
git checkout Copter-4.0.4
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd ~

# install Gazebo 11
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install gazebo libgazebo-dev
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/khancyr/ardupilot_gazebo.git
cd ardupilot_gazebo
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..   <-- Issue occurs here
make -j4
sudo make install
echo 'source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=~/ardupilot_gazebo/models' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

echo "# Reboot your computer for SITL to work #"
echo "# use `mamba activate ros_env` to use ROS Noetic #"
echo 'echo "# use \"mamba activate ros_env\" to use ROS Noetic #"' >> ~/.bashrc

I'm trying to follow these instructions to add a LiDAR to a gazebo model, but everything in that tutorial is old/deprecated and I couldn't figure out how to get some of the older packages since they're no longer supported. I decided to use ROS Noetic because it's the only version of ROS 1 that's still supported, and that works so far. If I can get Gazebo 11 to work I think I'll be able to follow the tutorial and add my LiDAR.
Edit: I tried the script on Ubuntu 20.04 and I changed the line
sudo apt-get install gazebo libgazebo-dev

to
sudo apt-get install gazebo11 libgazebo11-dev

and I still get the same issue.
